# How to login to a page from different text field

Tags: php, javascript, html

So to sum it all up, I have an `ownCloud` page with the average `login-page,` but I recently made a new login field on my HTML website with `"username"` and "`password`" fields + the `login button.`

What I'm trying to do is to make it so when they fill out that `login field` and click login, it automatically logs them into `ownCloud`.

How would I manage to do this?

Comment: Did you try to retrieve the `<form>` action attribute of the ownCloud login page, and to POST you're login page to this action?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="http://url.to.owncloud.login.page" method="post">
[your fields]
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cURL for automatically logs them into ownCloud.

Try this :

http://www.codekites.com/remote-login-with-curl-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you hosting both file "***ownCloud page***" and "***Your HTML page***" inside the same server then you just use PHP ***header function*** to redirect the user after successful login.